# Object has no method "open" error when using indexedDB

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I'm trying to build a small class-like container that will make it a little cleaner to load and store data from the HTML5 IndexedDB. To be honest this is the first time I've ever played with this feature, so my issue could be trivial.

I'm basing my code off of this tutorial:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/

```js
function DBDictionary()
{
    this.Holder = {};
    this.Entries = new Array();
    this.Opened = false;
    this.v = "1.0";
    this.Holder.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB;

    if ('webkitIndexedDB' in window)
    {
        window.IDBTransaction = window.webkitIDBTransaction;
        window.IDBKeyRange = window.webkitIDBKeyRange;
    }

    this.Holder.indexedDB = {};
    this.Holder.indexedDB.db = null;

    this.Holder.indexedDB.onerror = function(e) 
    {
        console.log(e);
    };

    this.DownloadDB = function()
    {
        if(this.Opened) return;
        var request = this.Holder.indexedDB.open("Storage");
        request.onsuccess = function(e)
        {
            this.Holder.indexedDB.db = e.target.result;
            var db = this.Holder.indexedDB.db;
            // We can only create Object stores in a setVersion transaction;
            if (v!= db.version)
            {
                var setVrequest = db.setVersion(v);

                // onsuccess is the only place we can create Object Stores
                setVrequest.onerror = this.Holder.indexedDB.onerror;
                setVrequest.onsuccess = function(e)
                {
                    if(db.objectStoreNames.contains("Storage")) db.deleteObjectStore("Storage");
                    var store = db.createObjectStore("Storage", {keyPath: "Key"});
                    this.PopulateAll();
                };
            }
            else
            {
                this.PopulateAll();
            }
        };

        request.onerror = this.Holder.indexedDB.onerror;
    };

    this.UploadDB = function()
    {       
        this.DeleteAll();
        this.SaveAll();
    };

    this.DeleteAll = function()
    {
        var db = this.Holder.indexedDB.db;
        var trans = db.transaction(["Storage"], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
        var store = trans.objectStore("Storage");

        Entries.forEach(function(element, index, array)
        {
            var request = store.delete(index);

            request.onerror = function(e)
            {
                console.log("Error Deleting: ", e);
            };
        });
    };

    this.PopulateAll = function()
    {
        var db = this.Holder.indexedDB.db;
        var trans = db.transaction(["Storage"], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
        var store = trans.objectStore("Storage");

        // Get everything in the store;
        var keyRange = IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(0);
        var cursorRequest = store.openCursor(keyRange);

        cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e)
        {
            var result = e.target.result;

            //No more results to load
            if(!!result == false)
            {
                if(!this.Opened) this.Opened = true;
                return;
            }

            this.Entries[result.Key] = result.Value;
            result.continue();
        };

        cursorRequest.onerror = this.Holder.indexedDB.onerror;
    };

    this.SaveAll = function()
    {
        var db = this.Holder.indexedDB.db;
        var trans = db.transaction(["Storage"], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
        var store = trans.objectStore("Storage");

        Entries.forEach(function(element, index, array)
        {
            var data = {
                "Key": index,
                "Value": element,
                "timeStamp": new Date().getTime()
            };

            var request = store.put(data);

            request.onerror = function(e) {
                console.log("Error Adding: ", e);
            };
        });
    };
}

function main()
{
    var dictionary = new DBDictionary();
    dictionary.DownloadDB();

    dictionary.Entries["hello"] = "world";
    alert(dictionary.Entries["hello"]);
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

My desired implemented state should look something like this:

```
function main()
{
    var dictionary = new DBDictionary();
    dictionary.DownloadDB();

    dictionary.Entries["hello"] = "world";
    alert(dictionary.Entries["hello"]);
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

What this should do is download the data from the browser's IndexedDB object and store them into the object-housed array Entries. When I want to store the value of Entires back into the DB, I would call dictionary.UploadDB();

However, I'm getting the single javascript error: **Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'open'**. I'm pretty much at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone offer me some tips?

Comment: You are probably using a browser that does not support IndexDB

Comment: No, it does; I'm using the latest version of Chrome. Simply following the tutorial works fine, but my implementation doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a typeof check and `console.log` the `this.Holder.indexedDB` object to inspect the prototype. Does it inherit the `IDBDatabase` prototype? If it does, the `open` method would be available to you.

If your `window.indexedDB` did fire the on success callback, `e.target.result` would be the correct way to access the newly opened database via the event object. But the fact that you're not getting that far suggests that your `this.Holder.indexedDB` object is not actually an instance of an `IDBDatabase`.

**EDIT**: Yes, this is exactly your issue. If you console.log the this.holder.indexedDB object you get an object that looks like `{"db":null}`.

Swap `this.Holder.indexedDB` for `window.webkitIndexedDB` at your `open` invocation and you'll see that 'world' alert pops. JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/7teS7/).

Comment: Footnote: This code is going to only work in Chrome because the HTML5Rocks example you base it on uses the older spec (pre-Dec 2011). When you open a database in the current spec you need to pass a version number and implement an `onupgradeneeded` callback.

Comment: Forgot to set this as the answer from a while back, but you were right on the money. Thanks!